# Possible to override the access restrictions on .Net assemblies?

Tags: .net, reflection, assemblies, access-modifiers, il

I need to take an assembly compiled for Metro and basically check that some compiler-generated code works from a regular console program(which should be very easy). My problem is that the compiler generated code emits everything of interest as internal and/or private (class and methods).

Is there anyway to specify that my console program is like a super-friend or something? Also, ugly hacks are acceptable, this is only for an integration test. What would be the best way of doing this though? The only two ways that come to mind to me is a LOT of reflection, or disassembling to IL, use some really complex regex and replace all private/internal members with public.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there anyway to specify that my console program is like a super-friend or something?

You can use [`InternalsVisibleToAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.internalsvisibletoattribute.aspx) - applying it to the "target" assembly, referencing the console application. That won't give you access to *private* members, but it should be fine if `internal` access is good enough.

The only immediate caveat is that I don't know for sure that the attribute works on Metro assemblies... but it's certainly worth a try.

Comment: Then is the only way to access private members through reflection?

Comment: Heh, actually ended up trying this and am greeted by "the project targets .NetFramwork while the file reference targets .NETCore. This is not a supported scenario" I guess I get to have fun stripping these functions out or something with Mono.Cecil